# Thread.Sleep() doesn't work with Cv2.ImShow, OpenCvSharp, C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, opencv

Very Simple C# Winforms App, OpenCVSharp4, Thread.Sleep() doesn't work.
It seems like (as I guess) Cv2 cannot be used in multiple threads, eg, one thread create NamedWindow, another thread ImShow. But this simple code below is still confusing.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture("E:/RankingBack.mp4");
        Mat frame = new Mat();

        while (true)
        {
            video.Read(frame);
            Cv2.ImShow(" ", frame);
            //Cv2.WaitKey(33);  // WORKS
            Thread.Sleep(33);   // DOES NOT WORK
        }

        frame.Dispose();
        video.Release();
        Cv2.DestroyAllWindows();

    }
```

Comment: Define "does not work" in this context.

Comment: since you're still fairly new on this site, may I suggest taking the [tour]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitKey`'s purpose is not waiting, it's to ***spin the GUI event loop*** that OpenCV uses. If you don't call it, OpenCV's GUI doesn't work.

You're using C# and WinForms already (judging by the tags), so you should use WinForms instead of `imshow`. OpenCV does its own GUI event handling, which **may conflict** with other GUI toolkits that are being used in the same program.

OpenCV's GUI functions are generally *not* safe to call from threads because some GUI backends don't allow that. That's irrelevant though because...

You **do not have** a "thread" here. You have the handler for a button click event. That's executed by the event loop of your WinForms application. That happens in the main thread that is always there in every process. That is not a spawned thread.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is a simple sample from my real code, which is running inside a task,Thread.Sleep() doesn't work also. The reason why I don't use Forms.PictureBox is that I tried to save ToBitmap() function. In my situation (video playback), I need to save every cpu tick. But now I'll back to PictureBox. Thanks again for your very detailed explanation.